# How to set the timezone in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, timezone, utc

In my django project's `settings.py` file, I have this line :

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

But I want my app to run in UTC+2 timezone, so I changed it to

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC+2'
```

It gives the error `ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: UTC+2`. What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Here is the list of valid timezones:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

You can use

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul'
```

for UTC+02:00

Comment: Actually that's only right half the year when DST is not on. You can use Africa/Mbabane for UTC+2 year round

Answer (score 42):

To get a set of all valid timezone names (ids) from [the tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html), you could [use `pytz` module in Python](http://pythonhosted.org//pytz/):

```
>>> import pytz # $ pip install pytz
>>> pytz.all_timezones_set
LazySet({'Africa/Abidjan',
         'Africa/Accra',
         'Africa/Addis_Ababa',
         'Africa/Algiers',
         'Africa/Asmara',
         'Africa/Asmera',
         ...
         'UTC',
         'Universal',
         'W-SU',
         'WET',
         'Zulu'})
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that there is a shorter list of timezone, not including deprecated ones with `pytz.common_timezones`.

Answer (score 14):

Choose a valid timezone from the [tzinfo database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). They tend to take the form e.g. `Africa/Gaborne` and `US/Eastern`

Find the one which matches the city nearest you, or the one which has your timezone, then set your value of `TIME_ZONE` to match.

Answer (score 11):

Valid timeZone values are based on the tz (timezone) database used by Linux and other Unix systems. The values are strings (xsd:string) in the form “**Area/Location**,” in which:

**Area** is a continent or ocean name. Area currently includes:

- Africa
- America (both North America and South America)
- Antarctica
- Arctic
- Asia
- Atlantic
- Australia
- Europe
- Etc (administrative zone. For example, “Etc/UTC” represents
  Coordinated Universal Time.)
- Indian
- Pacific

**Location** is the city, island, or other regional name.

The zone names and output abbreviations adhere to POSIX (portable operating system interface) UNIX conventions, which uses positive (+) signs west of Greenwich and negative (-) signs east of Greenwich, which is the opposite of what is generally expected. For example, “Etc/GMT+4” corresponds to 4 hours behind UTC (that is, west of Greenwich) rather than 4 hours ahead of UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) (east of Greenwich).

[Here is a list all valid timezones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJmzp.png)

You can change time zone in your settings.py as follows

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: I'm in Asia/Dhaka and all my times are 6 hours behind the current time...
What do i do to solve this issue

Comment: TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dhaka'

Answer (score 10):

This works just fine for me (I am still testing the app locally).
In `settings.py` file type:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Beirut'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False
```

#use your own TIME_ZONE:
https://gist.github.com/heyalexej/8bf688fd67d7199be4a1682b3eec7568

Comment: Need to specify `USE_TZ` to False to force the entire app to make use of the selected `TIME_ZONE`.

Answer (score 8):

Universal solution, based on Django's [TZ name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) support:

```
UTC-2 = 'Etc/GMT+2'
UTC-1 = 'Etc/GMT+1'
UTC = 'Etc/GMT+0'
UTC+1 = 'Etc/GMT-1'
UTC+2 = 'Etc/GMT-2'
```

+/- is intentionally switched.

Answer (score 4):

I found this question looking to change the timezone in my Django project's `settings.py` file to the United Kingdom.

Using the tz database in jfs' solution I found the answer:

```
    TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Change the TIME_ZONE to your local time zone, and keep USE_TZ as True in 'setting.py':

   TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'

   USE_I18N = True

   USE_L10N = True

   USE_TZ = True
2. This will write and store the datetime object as **UTC** to the backend database.
3. Then use *template tag* to convert the UTC time in your frontend template as such:

   ```
               <td> 
                   {% load tz %}
                   {% get_current_timezone as tz %}
                   {% timezone tz %}
                       {{ message.log_date | time:'H:i:s' }}
                   {% endtimezone %} 
               </td>
   ```

or use the *template filters* concisely:

```
                <td> 
                    {% load tz %}
                    {{ message.log_date | localtime | time:'H:i:s' }}
                </td>
```

4. You could check more details in the official doc: [Default time zone and current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/timezones/)

   When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

Answer (score 2):

Add Preferred TIME_ZONE and set USE_TZ to False like following

- TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
- USE_TZ = False

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list of valid timezones:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

You can use the Time zone For Dhaka

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dhaka'
```

for UTC+06:00 (Dhaka or Astana)

Answer (score 1):

1. download latest pytz file (pytz-2019.3.tar.gz) from:

   ```
   https://pypi.org/simple/pytz/
   ```
2. copy and extract it to `site_packages` directory on yor project
3. in cmd go to the extracted folder and run:

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```
4. `TIME_ZONE = 'Etc/GMT+2'` or country name

Answer (score 1):

Use Area/Location format properly.
Example:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```