# Django how to set default timezone?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I create a django project, but the default timezone is not correct.I have try to find something about how to correct it, but it still doesn't work.So, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `TIME_ZONE` in your `settings.py` file?

Check [How to set the timezone in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311354/how-to-set-the-timezone-in-django) for more info.

If this doesn't solve your problem, could you please include your code?

Comment: I found the timezone(`TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'`) from the link you add.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You toggle everything inyour `settings.py` Timezones should be [activated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#use-tz) in your project. That's the default:

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = <your Timezone>
```

If you've done this and still face issues, [please note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE):

> Django cannot reliably use alternate time zones in a Windows environment. If you’re running Django on Windows, TIME_ZONE must be set to match the system time zone.

Comment: I use iMac, I find the code `TIME_ZONE =UTC USE_TZ = True `, and I set `TIME_ZONE  = Asia/Shanghai`, finally it works correctly.You did me a great favor.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `TIME_ZONE` might work if you run the application on your laptop. For production code set `TZ` environmental variable (for example in the docker) based on where the code is being deployed to keep the times correct.