# django python DateTimeField different from admin input and database

Tags: python, django

I have django app that submit date from the `admin.py`.

here my `models.py`

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    datetimes = models.DateTimeField('Tanggal')
    uid = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='employeeattedance')
```

here the result:

[image]

there are different from the admin (local time) and my database.

why this happen?...

Comment: because of this `TIME_ZONE = 'your_time_zone'` in your `settings.py`

Comment: my setting TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' how to set GMT+7 ?...

Comment: TIME_ZONE = "Etc/GMT+7"

Comment: `now()` result `21:53:17`, set `TIME_ZONE = 'Etc/GMT+7'` result still difference `14:53:05`

Comment: is there no change? are data of your database already registered with a date time?

Comment: yes, didn't happen anything. i don't know, I am using `django.db.backends.sqlite3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170553/discussion-between-dicky-raambo-and-lemayzeur).

Comment: follow this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311354/how-to-set-the-timezone-in-django` also didn't affect anything. restart server also same.

Comment: In case data already register in db, you will not see any effect.. try to add new object to see the change

Comment: yes I know, I always do try insert data after change. but no effect, this is uncommon.