# Unable to convert UTC timestamp to local time in templates

Tags: python, django

I'm having difficulty converting this timestamp value to local time using the template tags provided in the Django documentation:

```
 {% load tz %}
 {% get_current_timezone as TIME_ZONE %}
 {{ private_message.timestamp|timezone:TIME_ZONE|date:'m/d/Y: h:i a' }}
```

I've tried many different template tags include `load localtime` and others. Regardless, the time still displays as UTC.

Settings:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

And I'm saving the timestamp as `timezone.now()` in my views.py

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The point is, your timezone is still set to UTC.

```py
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

So, for something like UTC+2, you can use

```py
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul'
```

You can visit all the valid timezones [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311392)

**EDIT**

Can you try using this to get the local date?

```py
from django.utils.timezone import localtime, now

# get now datetime based upon django settings.py TZ_INFO
localtime(now())
```

Comment: but isn't there a way to store the data in UTC, but then convert the time locally in templates for the user?

Comment: @winston Did you find the solution?