# Django convert local time to utc time

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, pytz

This is my code using this i am converting my time to in utc time :

```
pickup_time = "03:00 PM"

local_time = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
naive_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime (pickup_time, "%I:%M %p")
local_datetime = local_time.localize(naive_datetime, is_dst=None)
utc_datetime = local_datetime.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(utc_datetime)
print(utc_datetime.strftime("%I:%M %p"))
```

In result i am getting like :

1900-01-01 09:07:00+00:00

09:07 AM

but according to me it should be 09:30 AM .in IST offset of UTC+05:30  but i am getting 6 hours.
can anyone please suggest me what i am doing wrong here .

Comment: Is there any solution ?? i am stuck here

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **settings.py** like this, there is no need for this mess

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311392/13959928)