# tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, timezone

I am building a BlogPost Webapp and I am stuck on an Error.

When i try to check browser then it is keep showing

> tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'datetime.datetime'.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def age(self):
        current_datetime = datetime.now(tz=timezone.now())
        return (current_datetime - self.time).days
```

I also tried to change the time zone by :-

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> d = datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
>>> pacific = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
>>> pacific
<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>
>>> pacific_date = pacific.localize(d)
>>> pacific_date
datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 17, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
```

BUT Still same error

I have no idea, What is causing that Error.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: I presume this line is throwing the error: `current_datetime = datetime.now(tz=timezone.now())` - what is `timezone` in this context?

Comment: You mean, What `timezone` i am in ?

Comment: `timezone.now()` reads like you're using a datetime object here. That won't work. You need a time zone object (tzinfo), e.g. `pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')`.

Comment: actually, are you looking for [How to set the timezone in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29311354/10197418)

Comment: @test i hope you got the answer :P