# How to set a specific time zone in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, time, timezone

In django, it only has UTC timezone and other countries, but I live in Texas and there's like a five hour difference. How do I specify central time zone in my settings.py?

Comment: Seems like there are answers already try checking these.
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311354/how-to-set-the-timezone-in-django>

Comment: You can see available timezones here; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: @sajeyksmwangi I already saw that, and they only have country specifications available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your current time and see the difference between `UTC`. It will match any of them in the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

But, the best practice is using `UTC` if your users stay in different locations.

You can use `America/Panama` timezone which is equal to Texas.